# ASP.NET/C# - ASPxGridView Conditional Formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to only highlight the one cell and not the whole row however, when I use this code:

```
public bool ProcessSelectionChangedOnServer { get; set; }

protected void ASPxGridView1_HtmlDataCellPrepared(object sender,
DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.GetValue("BusType").ToString() == "CUS")
    {
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
    }
}
```

It seems to highlight the whole row where `BusType` is equal to "CUS". Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I tried to add

```
e.DataColumn.CellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
```

and remove the `e.Cell.BackColor` line but that did not highlight anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across a few comments that actually solved my answer. The fix was easy, I have to ensure that the Column that was being checked was the correct one.

Reference:

[ASPxGridView - Cell Conditional Formatting](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q307285)

Code:

```
 if (e.DataColumn.FieldName == "BusType")
    {
        if (e.GetValue("BusType").ToString() == "CUS")
        {
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
            e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;
            // and so on...
        }
    }
```